transform JSON objects in array with Nifi JoltTransformJson
I am using JOLTTransformJson Processor in Nifi.
My Json Input format are the 4 types of follows as below:
[
  {
    "a": "1"
  }
]

or
[
  {
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2"
  }
]

or
[
  {
    "a": "1"
  },
  {
    "a": "3"
  }
] 

or
[
  {
    "a": "1",
    "b": "2"
  },
  {
    "a": "3",
    "b": "4"
  }
]

The JSON format shows as those 4 types, and follow the rules:

attribute number in a json object may have one or more;
object number in top array structure may have one or more;
attributes in every object are the same.

I'm try to transform all format JSON Arrays with on JSON spec,
my JSON spec is:
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "$": "[#2].fieldName",
          "@": "[#2].fieldValue"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

I want transform JSON arrays into the form as below:
[
  {
    "fieldName": "a",
    "fieldValue": "1"
  }
]

or
[
  {
    "fieldName": "a",
    "fieldValue": "1"
  },
  {
    "fieldName": "b",
    "fieldValue": "2"
  }
]

or
[
  [
    {
      "fieldName": "a",
      "fieldValue": "1"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "fieldName": "a",
      "fieldValue": "3"
    }
  ]
]

or
[
  [
    {
      "fieldName": "a",
      "fieldValue": "1"
    },
    {
      "fieldName": "b",
      "fieldValue": "2"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "fieldName": "a",
      "fieldValue": "3"
    },
    {
      "fieldName": "b",
      "fieldValue": "4"
    }
  ]
]

but the JSON spec cannot process all the case especially more objects or more attributes, there's a wrong output simple as:
[
  {
    "fieldName": [
      "a",
      "a"
    ],
    "fieldValue": [
      "1",
      "3"
    ]
  },
  {
    "fieldName": [
      "b",
      "b"
    ],
    "fieldValue": [
      "2",
      "4"
    ]
  }
]

I'm using a debug tool at
Jolt Transform Demo Using v0.1.1
Please help to fix the JSON spec, thanks very much !

You can start with the qualifiers which are not wrapped within square brackets such as &2.&1...
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "$": "&2.&1.fieldName",
          "@": "&2.&1.fieldValue"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[#1]"
      }
    }
  }
]

that will handle all of the four cases.
